# Multiple LEFT JOINS are not working as expected in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

Multiple LEFT JOINS are not working as expected in Azure Stream Analytics.

I am using LEFT joins in Azure Stream Analytics and getting values for the first Two JOINS and null value for the rest of the LEFT JOIN

The below is the Json input i have used.

```
[
{"ID":"006XXXXX",
"ABC":
[{"E":1557302231320,"V":54.799999237060547}],
"XYZ":
[{"E":1557302191899,"V":31.0},{"E":1557302231320,"V":55}],
"PQR":
[{"E":1557302191899,"V":33},{"E":1557302231320,"V":15}],
"IJK":
[{"E":1557302191899,"V":65},{"E":1557302231320,"V":09}],

{"ID":"007XXXXX",
"ABC":
[{"E":1557302195483,"V":805.375},{"E":1557302219803,"V":0}],
"XYZ":
[{"E":1557302219803,"V":-179.0},{"E":1557302195483,"V":88}],
"PQR":
[{"E":1557302219803,"V":9.0},{"E":1557302195483,"V":98}],
"IJK":
[{"E":1557302219803,"V":1.0},{"E":1557302195483,"V":9}]
]
```

Below is the Query I used.

```
WITH 
ABCINNERQUERY AS (
    SELECT
        event.ID as ID,
        event.TYPE as TYPE,
        ABCArrayElement.ArrayValue.E as TIME,
        ABCArrayElement.ArrayValue.V as ABC
    FROM
        [YourInputAlias] as event
    CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.ABC) AS ABCArrayElement
),
XYZINNERQUERY AS (
    SELECT
        event.ID as ID,
        event.TYPE as TYPE,
        XYZArrayElement.ArrayValue.E as TIME,
        XYZArrayElement.ArrayValue.V as XYZ
    FROM
        [YourInputAlias] as event
    CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.XYZ) AS XYZArrayElement
),
PQRINNERQUERY AS (
    SELECT
        event.ID as ID,
        event.TYPE as TYPE,
        PQRArrayElement.ArrayValue.E as TIME,
        PQRArrayElement.ArrayValue.V as PQR
    FROM
        [YourInputAlias] as event
    CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.PQR) AS PQRArrayElement
),
IJKINNERQUERY AS (
    SELECT
        event.ID as ID,
        event.TYPE as TYPE,
        IJKArrayElement.ArrayValue.E as TIME,
        IJKArrayElement.ArrayValue.V as IJK
    FROM
        [YourInputAlias] as event
    CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.IJK) AS IJKArrayElement
),
KEYS AS
(
    SELECT 
        ABCINNERQUERY.ID AS ID, 
        ABCINNERQUERY.TIME as TIME
    FROM ABCINNERQUERY
        UNION 
    SELECT 
        XYZINNERQUERY.ID AS ID, 
        XYZINNERQUERY.TIME as TIME
    FROM XYZINNERQUERY
    UNION
    SELECT 
        PQRINNERQUERY.ID AS ID, 
        PQRINNERQUERY.TIME as TIME
    FROM PQRINNERQUERY
    UNION
    SELECT 
        IJKINNERQUERY.ID AS ID, 
        IJKINNERQUERY.TIME as TIME
    FROM IJKINNERQUERY
)

SELECT
    KEYS.ID as ID,
    KEYS.TIME as TIME,
    ABCINNERQUERY.ABC AS ABC,
    XYZINNERQUERY.XYZ AS XYZ,
    PQRINNERQUERY.PQR AS PQR,
    IJKINNERQUERY.IJK AS IJK
INTO [YourOutputAlias] 
FROM KEYS
    LEFT JOIN ABCINNERQUERY
    ON DATEDIFF(minute, KEYS, ABCINNERQUERY) BETWEEN 0 AND 10
    AND KEYS.ID = ABCINNERQUERY.ID
    AND KEYS.TIME = ABCINNERQUERY.TIME
    LEFT JOIN XYZINNERQUERY
    ON DATEDIFF(minute, KEYS, XYZINNERQUERY) BETWEEN 0 AND 10
    AND KEYS.ID = XYZINNERQUERY.ID
    AND KEYS.TIME = XYZINNERQUERY.TIME
    LEFT JOIN PQRINNERQUERY                                         ---From here onwards JOIN will not work. Only first two joins are working as expected.
    ON DATEDIFF(minute, KEYS, PQRINNERQUERY) BETWEEN 0 AND 10
    AND KEYS.ID = PQRINNERQUERY.ID
    AND KEYS.TIME = PQRINNERQUERY.TIME
    LEFT JOIN IJKINNERQUERY                                         ---Once we shift this join to 1st or 2nd then it will work.
    ON DATEDIFF(minute, KEYS, IJKINNERQUERY) BETWEEN 0 AND 10
    AND KEYS.ID = IJKINNERQUERY.ID
    AND KEYS.TIME = IJKINNERQUERY.TIME
```

Actual result is as below.

```
ID           STIME                  ABC      XYZ    PQR IJK
006XXXXX    1557302231320.00    54.79999924    31   null    null
006XXXXX    1557302191899.00    null            31  null    null
007XXXXX    1557302195483.00    805.375         88  null    null
```

Expected values for PQR and IJK for the corresponding time.

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you? If so,would you please accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your sample data and got 0 rows.Notice that the value you provided in the sample data is not right.

[image]

`09` can't be serialized for the number type.I fixed that then the sql works for me.

[image]